# Dar um return no if em jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso dar um return nesse if para passar no ajax o valor da página? A função traz por padrão o valor null. Daí eu pego no if e vejo e for nulo ele é igual a 1 e se for maior que o total, receberá o valor. Mas preciso fazer com que ele retorne os valores dos ifs para poder passar na url.

```js
function retorna_cliente(valor) {
  var id_cliente = "";
  var nome_cliente = "";
  var data_nascimento_cliente = "";
  var telefone_cliente = "";
  var celular_cliente = "";
  var cpf_cliente = "";
  var cnpj_cliente = "";
  var endereco_cliente = "";
  var email_cliente = "";
  var cliente = "";
  var mostra_dados_pessoa = "";
  var container_mostra_cliente = $('.mostra_clientes');
  var itemHTML = "";
  var mensagem_cliente = "Nenhum cliente encontrado";
  var quantidade = $("#qtd").val();
  var total_page = "";
  var page = "";

  var total = sessionStorage.getItem('last_page');
  if (valor == null) {
    valor = 1;
  }
  if (valor > total) {
    valor = total;
  }
  alert(valor);

  $.ajax({
        url: url_base + "clientes?qtd=" + quantidade + "&page=" + valor,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var retorno = data.clientes.data;
            if (retorno == 0) {
              $('.classe-clientes').css('display', 'none');
              $('.cliente-error-registro').css('display', 'block');
              $('.cliente-error-registro .mensagem-erro').html(mensagem_cliente);
            } else {
              //faz o resto
```

Comment: Não vejo nenhuma função nesse código. Podes mostrar mais código para percebermos o enquadramento?

Comment: @Sergio já editei

Comment: N verdade se eu der um else if ele já funciona no alert ele já traz o valor. Mas se eu coloco o projeto online não funciona.

Comment: O ajax está dentro da função `retorna_cliente`? essa função retorna alguma coisa ou é só para enviar o ajax?